# Difference between spectral radiance and specific intensity for blackbodies

Tags: radiation, thermal-radiation

The spectral radiance of a blackbody is given by Planck's law $$B_{\nu}(\nu, T) = \frac{2 h\nu^{3}}{c^{2}}\frac{1}{e^{h\nu/k_{B}T}-1}.$$ It has units W$\cdot$sr$^{-1}$$\cdot$m$^{-2}$$\cdot$Hz$^{-1}$. The specific intensity of a blackbody is given by a very similar function $$I_{\nu}(\nu, T) = \frac{2 \pi h\nu^{3}}{c^{2}}\frac{1}{e^{h\nu/k_{B}T}-1} = \pi B_{\nu}.$$ It has the same units. What necessitates the factor $\pi$ in order to get from Planck's law to the specific intensity of a blackbody? Or am I getting caught up in insignificant conventions?

Comment: In my text books (e.g. Rybicki & Lightman, "Radiative Processes in Astrophysics", 1979, eqn.1.35), what you have written as $B_\nu$ is called the specific intensity. Your second equation is the flux from a uniformly bright surface and has been integrated over a solid angle.